# How to hide FAB in a particular layout/fragment?

Tags: fragment, navigation-drawer, hide, floating-action-button

Excuse me if I don't use correct terms but I'm pretty new in Android. I'm using a navigation drawer and some fragments to navigate through. The problem is that I have a FAB in my main activity shared with other layouts but I don't want it to appear in one of my layouts.

Note: I've seen other posts with info about this but all of them talk about a PageViewer but i don't have it in my MainActivity code, only in one of the fragments code to make a Slide Viewer on it, but i know it's no related to my fab or navigation drawer.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156179/how-to-hide-fab-on-a-particular-fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide FAB on a particular fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156179/how-to-hide-fab-on-a-particular-fragment)

Comment: Thanks for the answers but no. I added a note explaining that I don't use the PageViewer mentioned in that post.